# flask app not working: "POST /send%22 HTTP/1.1" 404

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm new to flask and am trying to make a simple app.

for some reason when I submit the form I get:

Not Found

```
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

and in the terminal I get:

```
"POST /send%22 HTTP/1.1" 404
```

my code for app.py:https://pastebin.com/P661A16m

index.html: https://pastebin.com/04s06bjR

code.html: https://pastebin.com/pNvNzQC7

(html files in /templates directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a quotation mark on line 8 of your `index.html`. The line should read:

```
<form method="POST" action="/send">
```